# Set up multiple services in Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, aws-ecs

I am new to Docker. I have these services (pm2 (backend), apache (UI and data-batches (php), GO services and Database (postgresql)) running in an application.

What is the best method to create a Docker image? My plan is to create a Docker image for each service (as data-batches as more hits) and link together in a single container/more container and load it in a single instance. Will this method work for me?

Comment: No, don't do that - that sounds like Docker-in-Docker for no good reason. Create a Docker image for each one, and then run them together using Docker Compose.

Comment: Thanks I will follow this method, Create a Docker image for each one, and then run them together using Docker Compose.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a docker-compose for your main service and add other services as dependencies to it. Refer to [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) for more details.

Sample docker-compose could be

```
web:
  image: example/my_web_app:latest
  links:
    - db
    - cache
  env:
    - CACHE_URL: redis:6379

db:
  image: postgres:latest

redis:
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

This ensures that redis and postgres are started before your Main service.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks will give a try for docker-compose method.